# Retrieve output of ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, process, stream

Say I have a function like this :

```
public String runCommand(parameters, boolean interactive)
{
    Process p = null;

    // some code

    try
    {
        final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(my_command);
        pb.inheritIO(); // So the output is displayed on the console
        p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
    }
    catch( IOException | InterruptedException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (interactive )
    {
        return p.exitValue() + "";
    }
    else
    {
        // return the stdout of the process p
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to return the standard output of the process I'm running through `ProcessBuilder`, only if the `interactive` boolean is set to `false`. However, I cannot figure how to redirect the standard output to a variable with `ProcessBuilder`. Please not that I used `inheritIO()` so when I use a function like `adb shell`, the shell is displayed in my console, which is the behaviour I want. So basically, as for now, I can **see** the standard output in the console, but I don't know how to return it in the function so I can use this value as a variable for future stuff.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
    Reader rdr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i; (i = rdr.read()) !=-1;) {
        sb.append((char)i);
    }
    String var = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is getting the output as and when the execution, like this:

```
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

    Process p;
    try {
        p = pb.start();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        String output = "";
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            log.info(line);
            output += line + "\n";
        }
        return output;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ...
    }
    return null;
```